# Creating a custom class with primitive data types Obj-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class

I'm trying to make a custom class to hold data in my iPhone app. I want a box object that will hold 2 variables, it's state (as an int) and whether it's filled or not. (as a bool) In my .h I have this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface box : NSObject
{
    BOOL filled;
    int state;
}

- (id)init;
-(void)setState:(int)thestate;
-(BOOL)isFilled;

-(BOOL)filled;
-(int)state;
-(void)setFilled:(BOOL)input;
-(void)setState:(int)input;
@end
```

and in my .m I have this:

```
#import "box.h"

@implementation box

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setState:0];
        [self setFilled:NO];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void) setState:(int)input
{
    state = input;
    [self setFilled:YES];
    if (state == 0)
    {
        [self setFilled:NO];
    }
}

-(int) getState
{
    return self.state;
}

-(BOOL)filled
{
    return self.filled;
}

-(void)setFilled:(BOOL)input
{
    filled = input;
}
@end
```

I'm making my own setters and getters because when I did `@property (nonatomic) int state;` I had problems. Whenever getState is called, I get a Program received signal: "SIGABRT" error. The console says:

```
-[box state]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e51970
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[box state]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e51970'
```

How do I fix this error?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Were you synthesizing the properties using `@synthesize` in your class implementation?

**EDIT** When a property is synthesized, by default the getter will be `propname` and not `getPropname`.

Comment: Yes, I synthesised it. I'll try changing it back to work with properties, I think I changed some stuff since then.

Comment: The `@property` way worked. Sorry that I submitted a whole question for such an easy fix.